# How do I reference (make use of) WebKit-Sharp in OSX?

Tags: c#, macos, webkit, monodevelop, rpm

I have a C#-project in MonoDevelop and I want to use WebKit-Sharp as suggested in this tutorial: http://shana.worldofcoding.com/en/programming.html. My problem is that I don't know how to reference/install WebKit in OSX.

I found rpm's (installation files) from the given repositories but I couldn't execute them with rpm5 and when I extracted them I didn't find any file that I was able to reference from my project.

I've been looking through https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp, but aren't sure if anything from there could do the job.

Can I reference anything from github or somewhere else to make WebKit work in MonoDevelop and OSX?

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the rpm for webkit-sharp, the dll is in ./usr/lib/mono/gac/webkit-sharp/somehash/webkit-sharp.dll
You should be able to import that into your References in the project (search for it from the .Net Assembly tab after you extract it).